# Conference and workshops

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Is there any website which keep track of the upcoming workshops and conferences in Mathematics and related areas. For me,manytimes come accross it after it's over. Is there any way to deal with this situation.

Comment: See the recent MathOverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119726/discovering-and-selecting-conferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are near a math library which has a subscription to the Notices of the American Mathematical Society or have a friend (or yourself) who is a member. the Notices has a section called Mathematical Calendar which lists conferences on math research. The current issue currently lists conferences in Singapore, Padua Italy, Boston MA, Los Angelos CA, Moscow Russia, Vienna Austria, Palo Alto CA, Ponta Delgada Portugal, West Lafayette IN, Boston MA, and that is only through May.  More countries and US cities in the rest of the year. There is a variant of this on the website http://www.ams.org under the tab for meetings at Mathematical Calendar.  This has less info on every conference but more conferences so the AMS might be a good place to start.