# Conferences dealing w/challenges of teaching higher level math to STEM audiences

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm interested in knowing whether there are conferences that have, among other topics, the difficulty of teaching higher level mathematical concepts to folks with prior established skills in STEM, e.g., software engineers.  An example paper topic might include assessing the difficulties of software engineers learning to use formal theorem and proof systems to help create better software.

I have seen in [1] that the AMS lists general math conferences, but I'm wondering if there are more focused, practical math conferences that deal with education and topics such as this, addressing education of a more technical audience (not an elementary education audience).  Such conferences may not be "math" conferences per se.

Thanks!

[1] [Conference and workshops](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289410)

Comment: Might this be a better question for [matheducators.se]?

Comment: Did not know about that stackexchange, thanks!